# How to create a TF Dataset from a tuple of tensor? (and best practices)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I'm having some problems with the creation of a custom Dataset.
Right now i managed to get a generator function:

```
def dataset_generator():
for path in pathlist_img:
    img, labels = process_path(path)
    yield img, labels
```

It returns two tensorflow tensor: the first one of shape=(720, 1280, 3), dtype=uint8, and the second one of shape=(?, 14), dtype=float32, where "?" means that it depends on the image (it's an object detection dataset, so the number of instances recognized isn't fixed).

I would like to have a Dataset with my images associated with my labels, so that's why im yielding tuples.

The problem is that my dataset

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(dataset_generator, ((tf.uint8, tf.uint8, tf.uint8),(tf.float32, tf.float32)))
```

it's just a

```
<FlatMapDataset shapes: ((<unknown>, <unknown>, <unknown>), (<unknown>, <unknown>)), types: ((tf.uint8, tf.uint8, tf.uint8), (tf.float32, tf.float32))>
```

And doesn't seem to contain anything, or at least i cant get anything out of it.

Is there some best practices to build a Dataset from images and labels file?
How can i fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try rewriting like this:

```
img = tf.ones((730, 1280, 3), dtype=tf.uint8)
label = tf.ones((tf.random.uniform(shape=[], minval=1, maxval=10), 14),
                dtype=tf.float32)
def gen():
    yield img,label

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
      gen,
      (tf.uint8, tf.float32),
)
```

In output types you should only specify the overall dtype of the overall tensor, not dtypes for each of it's dimensions.